# Using git without X11 forwarding

Tags: git, ssh, x11-forwarding

When I try to use git on a remote machine (via ssh), it complains of not being able to connect to my display. Since I'm using this ssh connection within a screen environment from different machines, I cannot use X11 forwarding. However, I do not want any graphical interface for typing in my password.

Command:

> $ git pull
>
> connect localhost port 6010: Connection refused
>
> (gnome-ssh-askpass:7316): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
>   localhost:36.0

Version:

> $ git --version
>
> git version 1.7.1

How can I get around the need for a graphical connection here?

Comment: what happens if you execute the ssh command without git on that machine?

Comment: This is possible and I get asked for the password in the terminal

Answer (score 1):

Please read the [`gitcredentials(7)`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitcredentials.html) manual page (you can run `git help credentials` to read it locally).

It explains how Git manages the problem of obtaining your credentials.

Namely, the usage of the `GIT_ASKPASS` environment variable might be of interest to you.

Alternatively, you could allow your SSH client to forward connection to your local agent (the thing which keeps your keys) so that Git running in the remote session could use the same identities.  Of coure, use this only if applicable (that is, the identities are the same).  In this case, SSH won't supposedly even try to ask for the password since it will be serviced by the agent.  Read the `ssh_config(5)` manual page and look for the `ForwardAgent` configuration option.

To reiterate, the root of your problem appears to be in that SSH needs to ask you for your credentials, and you have to make sure it doesn't. Hence maybe the solution is as simple as running `ssh-agent` in the remote session and `ssh-add`-ing the necessary identities to it before running Git or just making sure environment variables and Git configuration settings related to obtaining credentials for SSH have meaningful values.

Comment: git help credentials gives me: No manual entry for gitcredentials. The environmental variable GIT_ASKPASS does not exist / is empty.

Comment: Okay, I read through it online. Calling `export SSH_ASKPASS=""; git pull` solves the issue.